# Tomcat Catalina out log rotate and appending new lines

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

Application running on Tomcat is using log4j for some unknown reason is appending (randomly) new log lines somewhere in the middle of the log file

log4j.properites looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA
log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.CATALINA.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout=com.medallies.log.ThreadIdSupportedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern=[TID=%i] %-5p %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} | %c | %m%n
```

Tomcat restart will help in that case but after some time issue will come back after executing daily log rolling.

Any thought on that?